# Convert a rectangle to ranges of Hilbert numbers

Tags: spatial-index, spatial-query, hilbert-curve

When spatial data is represented using Hilbert numbers, a rectangular range is mapped to multiple ranges of Hilbert numbers. Is there any quick way to find this mapping without going through every cell the given rectangle, R, overlaps with? I can think of considering only the border cells of R and then sorting them... Is there any better way?

Thanks.